# Cannot find elements on home screen of iOS application

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am running test automation on an application on an iOS device, but when the user is logged in to the application, no elements can be found - but only on the home screen. I have tried finding elements in Appium inspector as well with no success.

When I do a getPageSource() on the aforementioned page I get this weird page source:

```java
var DeviceUserAgentBridge = { 
      getDeviceUserAgent: function getDeviceUserAgent() { 
      var deviceUserAgent = navigator.userAgent; 
      if (!deviceUserAgent || deviceUserAgent.length == 0) { 
          return null; 
      } 
      var userAgentInfo = { 
          "nol_useragent": deviceUserAgent 
      }; 
      return JSON.stringify(userAgentInfo) 
  } 
};
```

I only use the most basic capabilities:

```json
{ 
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "appium:platformVersion": "15.0",
  "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
  "appium:app": "theapp.app",
  "appium:deviceName": "iPhone SE (2nd generation)",
  "appium:udid": "theudid"
}
```

On every other page there can be elements found, it seems that only this page is having this "block".

I've tried many different capabilities and versions but always the same result.